# Does my application need to ask for a role on ec2 instance to configure the session or leave it empty?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to use the aws-sdk-go in my application. It's running on EC2 instance. Now in the Configuring Credentials of the doc,https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/, it says it will look in

```
*Environment Credentials - Set of environment variables that are useful when sub processes are created for specific roles.

* Shared Credentials file (~/.aws/credentials) - This file stores your credentials based on a profile name and is useful for local development.

*EC2 Instance Role Credentials - Use EC2 Instance Role to assign credentials to application running on an EC2 instance. This removes the need to manage credential files in production.`
```

Wouldn't the best order be the reverse order? But my main question is do I need to ask the instance if it has a role and then use that to set up the credentials if it has a role? This is where I'm not sure of what I need to do and how.

I did try a simple test of creating a empty config with essentially only setting the region and running it on the instance with the role and it seems to have "worked" but in this case, I am not sure if I need to explicitly set the role or not.

```
awsSDK.Config{
    Region:      awsSDK.String(a.region),
    MaxRetries:  awsSDK.Int(maxRetries),
    HTTPClient:  http.DefaultClient,
}
```

I just want to confirm is this the proper way of doing it or not. My thinking is I need to do something like the following

```
   role = use sdk call to get role on machine
   set awsSDK.Config { Credentials: credentials form of role,
            ...
       }

   issue service command with returned client.
```

Any more docs/pointers would be great!

Comment: Thank you Daniel and retgits both for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used the go SDK, but the AWS SDKs I used automatically use the EC2 instance role if credentials are not found from any other source.

Here's an AWS blog post explaining the approach AWS SDKs follow when fetching credentials: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/a-new-and-standardized-way-to-manage-credentials-in-the-aws-sdks/. In particular, see this:

> If you use code like this, the SDKs look for the credentials in this
>   order:
>
> 1. In environment variables. (Not the .NET SDK, as noted earlier.)
> 2. In the central credentials file (~/.aws/credentials or
>      %USERPROFILE%.awscredentials).
> 3. In an existing default, SDK-specific
>      configuration file, if one exists. This would be the case if you had
>      been using the SDK before these changes were made.
> 4. For the .NET SDK, in the SDK Store, if it exists.
> 5. If the code is running on an EC2
>      instance, via an IAM role for Amazon EC2. In that case, the code gets
>      temporary security credentials from the instance metadata service; the
>      credentials have the permissions derived from the role that is
>      associated with the instance.

Comment: Yes, that essentially what the docs say. I'm just confused as to if I have to explicitly query for a role on the instance and then somehow create credentials for it, or if I need to specify a role explicitly and no creds, or nothing at all.  I normally use the keys but that's not that secure correct?

Comment: If you specify nothing, it should automatically use the EC2 instance role. You can only have 1 EC2 instance role, so there's no need to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

In my apps, when I need to connect to AWS resources, I tend to use an access key and secret key that have specific predefined IAM roles. Assuming I have those two, the code I use to create a session is:

```
awsCredentials := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(awsAccessKeyID, awsSecretAccessKey, "")
awsSession = session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
            Credentials: awsCredentials,
            Region:      aws.String(awsRegion),
        }))
```

When I use this, the two keys are usually specified as either environment variables (if I deploy to a docker container).

A complete example: https://github.com/retgits/flogo-components/blob/master/activity/amazons3/activity.go

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I normally use the keys to connect as well, but my requirements have changed and I'm just confused as how to create a client and session without credentials and just a role. I'm not sure if I need to create the session by specifying the role or just let the SDK decide.

Comment: Ah okay, in that case I misunderstood, sorry! Does your code already run on AWS? In my Lambda's I use `awsSession = session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(awsRegion),}))` and it will automatically assume the role that my Lambda got when I deployed it.